# count most abundant species (cases) in matrix using R

Tags: r, count

I want to use some basic exploratory commands for my dataset, but can't figure this one out: i want to be able to have the ten (or any other number) most abundant species returned to me based on my data-matrix.

So, species that are present in all sites (rows) end up high in the ranking, species that are present in only one site end up low (and may even be excluded based on the ten most abundant species).

Furthermore, each species has a number that corresponds with its abundacy within the site (row). I also want to be able to get a top ten most abundant species based on abundancy rahter then presence absesence.

Here i used `dput` to give you a part of my dataset.

```
structure(list(Hypnum.jutlandicum = c(1L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 18L, 43L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 68L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 68L), Cladonia.floerkeana = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Dicranum.scoparium = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), Deschampsia.flexuosa = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Carex.pilulifera = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Polytrichum.commune = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Calluna.vulgaris = c(43L, 38L, 56L, 68L, 56L, 68L, 38L, 
88L, 68L, 38L, 68L, 88L, 38L, 38L, 18L, 8L, 18L, 38L), Danthonia.decumbens = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Genista.pilosa = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Polytrichum.juniperinum = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 68L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 0L), Micarea.erratica = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 
18L, 18L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L), Trapelia.coarctata = c(0L, 
0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
4L), Baeomyces.rufus = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
0L, 3L, 8L, 68L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Porpidia.crustulata = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Catillaria.chalybeia = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Rhizocarpon.reductum = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Porina.chlorotica = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Acarospora.fuscata = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Dibaeis.baeomyces = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Erica.tetralix = c(18L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 68L), Campylopus.introflexus = c(1L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
38L, 18L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L), Cladonia.coccifera = c(0L, 
4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
4L), Cladonia.grayi = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Agrostis.vinealis = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Cladonia.macilenta = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), Polytrichum.piliferum = c(0L, 
0L, 18L, 38L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L), Rumex.acetosella = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cladonia.ramulosa = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Hypochaeris.radicata = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Molinia.caerulea = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
0L), Carex.arenaria = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cladonia.fimbriata = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Pinus.sylvestris = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 0L), Quercus.robur = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Betula.pendula = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cephaloziella.divaricata = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Pseudoscleropodium.purum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cladonia.humilis = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L), Festuca.species = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Brachythecium.rutabulum = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Carex.panicea = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), Sorbus.aucuparia.1 = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Ceratodon.purpureus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), Polytrichum.formosum = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Bryum.capillare = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Lecidea.lithophila = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Amelanchier.lamarckii = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Salix.aurita.1 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L), Cephaloziella.species = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Betula.pubescens = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Lecidella.scabra = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Calamagrostis.epigejos = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Placynthiella.icmalea = c(0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Geranium.robertianum = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Micarea.lynceola = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Porpidia.soredizodes = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Scoliciosporum.umbrinum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Trapelia.obtegens = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Deschampsia.flexuosa.2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Rubus.plicatus.1 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Bryum.spec. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cladonia.monomorpha.1 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Geisleria.sychnogonoides = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L), Micarea.lignaria = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(274784L, 274553L, 
272517L, 275195L, 272514L, 274783L, 99L, 113L, 96L, 109L, 117L, 
102L, 114L, 97L, 138L, 133L, 95L, 237L))
```

I hope the question is clear, if not i will expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!Hi I think I understand your question.

The easiest way for me to think aobut this is by making a site variable, then taking your wide data and make it long as such:

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(site_no = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
   gather(species, abundance, -site_no)
```

Now we can filter sites that have abundance = 0 and the do some summarrising:

```
df %>% filter(abundance != 0) %>%
    group_by(species) %>%
    summarise(count = n(), 
              total =sum(abundance))
```

Here count is the number sites they are present in and total is the total number.  Using arrange on either variable and and subsetting will get you the answers you are interested in (using the -count or -total).

Comment: This works for me, thanks. I am not that into dplyr and tidyer, but i think its time to start using it more. Great solution, thanks!